# Make Thunderbird show message list like Outlook?

Tags: thunderbird

Does anyone know how to change the layout (either option or extension) for Thunderbird 3 to make it look like the default layout in Outlook?

Basically, in Vertical View, I can get my Folders on the left, next to a 2 line listing of each message (Sender and Time line 1, Subject on line 2), and Message Pane on right?

If not, I'll also take as Notes links to guides on how to make my own extension.

Comment: I've posted this in the mozilla support forums too.
Not totally sure if I understood it correctly, but it might be a bug.

http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=1802585

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://superuser.com/questions/1157404/how-to-make-thunderbirds-message-list-view-show-sender-and-subject-on-two-rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Thunderbird Extensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension)

> 1. Introduction (this page)
> 2. [The extension filesystem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_2%3a_extension_filesystem) (setting up your local system)
> 3. [Install manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_3%3a_install_manifest) (the install.rdf file that contains
>      meta-information about the extension)
> 4. [Chrome manifest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_4%3a_chrome_manifest) (list of packages and overlays)
> 5. [XUL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_5%3a_XUL) (the XML user interface language that is used to modify the
>      Thunderbird user interface)
> 6. [Installing locally](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_6%3a_installing_locally) (enabling the extension on your local Thunderbird
>      instance)
> 7. [Packaging](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_7%3a_packaging) (making a distribution package that contains the extension)
> 8. [Distributing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extensions/Thunderbird/Building_a_Thunderbird_extension_8%3a_distributing) (from your own site or from http://addons.mozilla.org/)