# How to make Thunderbird's message list view show sender and subject on two rows (like the macOS Mail app)?

Tags: email, thunderbird, layout

Is it possible to make the Thunderbird message list display each message as two rows (one row for the sender, and one row for subject, like Mac Mail does?)

Here is what my version of Thunderbird (version 45) shows:

> [image: Thunderbird message list row]

And here is what I'd like Thunderbird to be able to show (screenshot from Mac Mail):

> [image: Mac Mail message list row]

Comment: Not really an answer as it's not released yet but apparently we will get this soon :) https://www.askvg.com/thunderbird-to-get-multi-line-message-list-view-in-version-114/

Answer (score 1):

This is impossible with the current UX (User Interface) framework that Thunderbird uses.

See: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=213945

There are some bug bounties out there, but no one has picked up the torch for it yet.

Comment: No longer impossible it seems: Following that bugzilla link I see that a developer has this issue in their sights, so it looks like this feature will get added, but no sense of when (see posts in Feb 2020 and May 2020).

Comment: Already possible and has been implemented in Betterbird. See https://www.betterbird.eu.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, Thunderbird cannot do multi-line view as per your question. However, [**Betterbird**](https://www.betterbird.eu), a fork of Thunderbird, has the feature. You might want to either wait for the feature to be implemented in Thunderbird, or simply use Betterbird for now.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This feature has now arrived in Thunderbird 115 (July 2023). It is called "card view".

See [this support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/getting-started-thunderbird-main-window-supernova#w_vertical-view-layout-with-card-view) on how to activate it.